# how can i place multiple test-suits in a single test-suit using Jest and supertest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, supertest

I have created multiple test-suites and want them to run under a single test suite or a single describe test block.
I have placed them like...

```
describe('',()=>{  
  require('test-suite1.test.ts')
  require('test-suite2.test.ts')
  require('test-suite3.test.ts')
  ...
  ....
}
```

**Can anyone suggest me anyother way to replace the require and still run all the test under single test suite?**

Comment: What's the issue about this `require` way?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Using this way I am not able to track which test suite is currently running it shows the result at the end of all test suites.

Answer (score 3):

The layout of your tests can be something like this:

```
describe('All of the functions from this file', () => {
  describe('first function', () => {
    test('first function test one', () => {
      // ... tests for the first function
    });
    test('first function test two', () => {
      // ... tests for the first function
    });
    test('first function test three', () => {
      // ... tests for the first function
    });

  });
  describe('second function', () => {
    test('second function test one', () => {
      // ... tests for the second function
    });
    test('second function test two', () => {
      // ... tests for the second function
    });
    test('second function test three', () => {
      // ... tests for the second function
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: yes it is like this only but I have different test suites in different file I want to access from a file, don't want to place all the code in one file.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this while looking for alternative ways of achieving this, but might as well share my current solution.

```
// suitOne.js
export const suitOne = () =>
  describe('some functionality', () => {
    it('tests smth', () => ...
  }

// suitTwo.js
export const suitTwo = () =>
  describe('some other functionality', () => {
    it('tests smth else', () => ...
  }

// allSuits.spec.js
import { suitOne } from './suitOne.js'
import { suitTwo } from './suitTwo.js'

suitOne()
suitTwo()
```

Test suits must be ran synchronously.